# find the derivative with fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I came to cos(cos(sin(x)^3)+sin(x)), which is incorrect. I have a hunch that the error is somewhere around the sin x and the exponent. I'm just not sure what to do to fix it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$g(u) = \int_{-1}^u \cos(t^3) + t ~ dt$$
Then $g'(u) = \cos(u^3) + u$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Using $F(x) = g(\sin(x))$ and the chain rule for derivatives, we have
$$\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (g(\sin(x))) = g'(\sin(x)) \cdot \sin'(x) = (\cos(\sin(x)^3) + \sin(x)) \cdot \cos(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The fundamental theorem of calculus is $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} F(t) \, dt=F(b(x)) b'(x)-F(a(x)) a'(x)$$

Applied to your case, this uses $F(t)=\cos(t^3)+t$, $a(x)=-1$, $b(x)=\sin(x)$ then $a'(x)=0$, $b'(x)=\cos(x)$.

I am sure that you can take from here and find where you made a mistake.